# Update user chosen cell from csv with pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to have a user update a cell within a csv using pandas. The issue I have with my code so far is that I can locate the values I want using iloc, but when it comes to actually writing the data to the csv, the csv file remains unchanged.

```
import pandas as pd

state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa",
           "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut",
           "District ", "of Columbia", "Delaware", "Florida",
           "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois",
           "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts",
           "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi",
           "Montana", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire",
           "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon",
           "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota",
           "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Virgin Islands", "Vermont", 
           "Washington", "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]

def update_population():
    df5 = pd.read_csv("statedata.csv", encoding='UTF8')
    update_pop = input("\nWhich state would you like to update?: ")
    if update_pop not in state_names:
        print("Invalid")
        update_population()
    else:
        found_state = df5[(df5['State'] == update_pop)]
        state_pop = (found_state.iloc[0]['State'])
        pop_pop = (found_state.iloc[0]['Population'])
        print("\nThe current population of ", state_pop, "is: ", pop_pop)
        updated_pop = int(input("\nPlease enter the new population value for " + state_pop + ":"))
    df5.replace({pop_pop: updated_pop}, inplace=True, regex=True)
    print("\nThe updated population of ", state_pop, "is: ", pop_pop)

update_population()
```

Thank you for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to edit the code to solve the issue and the csv updates as necessary.

```
"""Import print csv"""

import pandas as pd

state_names = ["Alaska", "Alabama", "Arkansas", "American Samoa",
               "Arizona", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut",
               "District ", "of Columbia", "Delaware", "Florida",
               "Georgia", "Guam", "Hawaii", "Iowa", "Idaho", "Illinois",
               "Indiana", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Massachusetts",
               "Maryland", "Maine", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Missouri", "Mississippi",
               "Montana", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Nebraska", "New Hampshire",
               "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "Nevada", "New York", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon",
               "Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota",
               "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Virginia", "Virgin Islands", "Vermont", "Washington",
               "Wisconsin", "West Virginia", "Wyoming"]


def update_population():
    """Update population"""
    df5 = pd.read_csv("statedata.csv", encoding='UTF8')
    update_pop = input("\nWhich state would you like to update?: ")
    if update_pop not in state_names:
        print("Invalid")
        update_population()
    else:
        found_state = df5[(df5['State'] == update_pop)]
        state_pop = (found_state.iloc[0]['State'])
        pop_pop = (found_state.iloc[0]['Population'])
        print("\nThe current population of ", state_pop, "is: ", pop_pop)
        updated_pop = int(input("\nPlease enter the new population value for " + state_pop + ":"))
        df5.loc[df5["State"] == state_pop, "Population"] = updated_pop
        df5.to_csv("statedata.csv", index=False)
        print("\nThe updated population of ", state_pop, "is: ", updated_pop)


update_population()
```